# Is there a modern equivalent to e4rat?

Tags: boot, ureadahead

I used to use e4rat to improve boot speed to great effect. However, lately, I've noticed that Ubuntu isn't starting e4rat properly, and its effect has diminished, vanished, in fact. In light of this, I was wondering if there was a modern alternative to e4rat (which hasn't been active for years it seems) which is faster than the default ureadahead.